# Black screen using glReadPixels(...) on Samsung s9

Tags: android, opengl-es, glreadpixels

For app reason I need to retrieve a screenshot of the screen, or to better say only the OpenGL drawn section. In all other devices my function works and uses the OpenGL primitive: "glReadPixels(...)"
On Galazy S9 the result is a buffer completely black, I've also try to use the "glGetError()" and it returns: "GL_NO_ERROR".
Have you some idea how can I solve it?

Comment: which OpenGL ES version? can you add the parameters you are using for glReadPixels()?

Comment: Which GPU? There are two versions of the Galaxy S9.

Comment: OpenGL ES version = 2
GPU= ARM Mali-G72 MP18

Comment: I want to include that I'm experiencing the same issue and am looking for an answer.